# Data.In.Add creates General Exception Error related to DNN Search indexing

Tags: 2sxc

I'm using the [FAQ with Categories](http://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/faq-with-categories-and-6-views) demo on my site, and I'm getting constant General Exception Errors in the DNN Log Viewer. All of these are related to "_All questions (sorted) of a selected category.cshtml" template, specifically line 13:

```
Data.In.Add("QandA", sorted["Default"]);
```

The exception error inner message is "An item with the same key has already been added." And below is the entire error copy/pasted in full:

> AbsoluteURL:
>
> DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
>
> ExceptionGUID:819672a9-e438-40cf-9e8e-c834b7f1cebb
>
> AssemblyVersion:
>
> PortalId:-1
>
> UserId:-1
>
> TabId:-1
>
> RawUrl:
>
> Referrer:
>
> UserAgent:
>
> ExceptionHash:pkLGSJcpAMGKl0ycv8+1+Q==
>
> Message:Search: Error while indexing module 724 on tab 202, portal 0
>
> StackTrace:
>
> InnerMessage:An item with the same key has already been added.
>
> InnerStackTrace:
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue
>   value, Boolean add)    at
>   ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_FAQ_with_Categories__All_questions__sorted__of_a_selected_category_cshtml.CustomizeData() in q:\dev-dnn.calarts.edu\Portals\0\2sxc\FAQ with Categories_All
>   questions (sorted) of a selected category.cshtml:line 13    at
>   ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.CustomizeData() in
>   C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy
>   Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 121    at
>   ToSic.SexyContent.Search.SearchController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo
>   moduleInfo, DateTime beginDate) in
>   C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\Search\SearchController.cs:line
>   68
>
> Source:
>
> FileName:
>
> FileLineNumber:0
>
> FileColumnNumber:0
>
> Method:
>
> Server Name: DEV-DNN

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your Data already has a stream "QandA" so you can't "Add" another one. If this is the case

1. either remove it first before adding
2. replace it with Data["QandA"] = ... instead of adding

Comment: Thanks. The first suggestion worked for me. I ended up doing `Data.In.Remove("QandA");` before `Data.In.Add`